# Given an Automation Element how do i simulate a single left click on it

Tags: c#, automation

```
AutomationElement child = walker.GetFirstChild(el);
```

using windows automation How do i simulator a left single click on Child ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try with:

```
AutomationElement child = walker.GetFirstChild(el);
System.Windows.Point p = child.GetClickablePoint();
Mouse.Move((int)p.X, (int)p.Y);
Mouse.Click(MouseButton.Left);
```

Links:
[AutomationElement.GetClickablePoint Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.getclickablepoint.aspx)
[Simulate mouse Enter/Move/Leave on WPF control without real mouse usage](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/0555c1ea-5b0f-4c5e-863c-b54eb510ad40)

**Edit for comment**

See this links:

[Mouse.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TestApi/blob/master/Releases/TestApi_v0.6/Sources/TestApiCore/Code/Input/Mouse.cs)
[NativeMethods.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TestApi/blob/master/Releases/TestApi_v0.6/Sources/TestApiCore/Code/Input/NativeMethods.cs)
[Introduction to TestApi – Part 1: Input Injection APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2008/12/15/9223397.aspx)

Comment: What should i reference to get access to Mouse class?

Comment: I will try this , although i think that just getting the x and y to click will cause the problem of the mouse not aware what its clicking so the element could be not on top of the window and that would cause the click to be at no where

Comment: If the element is hidden getclickablepoint does not return a valid point. I. Which case you can bring the window to the front first.

Comment: @Jack I don't know, you can ask to Stacker

Comment: Nevermind it. I thought it was relevant to get the right clickable point but it isn't.

Comment: @andresdescalzo some of your links are broken

Comment: links are again broken

Answer (score 23):

Rather than sending mouse events, you can `Invoke` it through the `InvokePattern` like so:

```
public void InvokeAutomationElement(AutomationElement automationElement)
{
    var invokePattern = automationElement.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
    invokePattern.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Not all windows support Invoke pattern

Comment: This is true, but I'm guessing that if you can click on it you can do it with automation (and not mouse clicking).  If it doesn't support the Invoke pattern, it probably supports the `SelectionItemPattern`, so you can `Select` it.

Comment: I've seen windows which only support WindowPattern and TransformPattern. From the question I cannot tell why the click is performed. It can be that Stacker wants to bring the window to focus (just a guess). So there's might be no immediate activity that is going to be "invoked".

Answer (score 3):

If the control has a "ClickablePoint" you can use this code

```
System.Windows.Point p = theButton.GetClickablePoint();
AutoItX3Lib.AutoItX3Class au3 = new AutoItX3Lib.AutoItX3Class();
au3.AutoItSetOption("MouseCoordMode", 0);
au3.MouseClick("LEFT", (int)p.X, (int)p.Y, 1, -1);
```

where [AutoItX3Lib](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) is the C# API for AutoIt (available on NuGet)