# UI Automation to press toolbar button in another application in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation

I am looking for a method to "click" a toolbar button in another application using the UIAutomation namespace.  The other application is not written by me and I don't have access to the source.

I found the parent window using:

```
AutomationElement _automationElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Other App"));
```

I found the toolbar element using:

```
AutomationElement _toolbarElement = _automationElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "ToolBar1"));
```

I've tried to navigate further into the toolbar element for decendents and children and they all returned null.  Is there a way to access the individual buttons contained within the toolbar?

Comment: Use a tool such as "Inspect" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects or "Accessibility Insights" https://accessibilityinsights.io/ to first check what elements you can get to using UI Automation. If you can see the element you're after, then you can get to it programmatically otherwise you can't

Comment: OK, thanks, that answers my question.  I was using Accessibility Insights and it shows the entire toolbar as one object.  I guess you can't drill down to the individual buttons of the toolbar.  I was hoping there was something simple that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar project, in my case I used this

```
    private AutomationElement FindButton(AutomationElement parent, string buttonName)
    {
        AutomationElementCollection list = parent.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants,
               new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button));
        foreach (AutomationElement element in list)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Current.Name) && element.Current.Name.Equals("button_name"))
            {
                return element;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

to find all visible buttons and then put in a variable the need one, however I'm still seeking an adequate method to do the click. [At this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105396/given-an-automation-element-how-do-i-simulate-a-single-left-click-on-it) there's a method but until now I didn't found the right `Mouse` class to use. If you can instead, please share.

EDIT: In the end I preferred another approach that worked pretty well

```
    private void ClickButton(AutomationElement button)
    {
        InvokePattern pat = button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
        pat.Invoke();
    }
```

The only thing I had to check is if the button have `IsInvokePatternAvailable: true` with Inspect.exe (part of Windows SDK)

Comment: This isn't quite the same thing as my situation....I'm dealing with a toolbar object that doesn't have descendents.  If I run a "AutomationElement.FindAll" it will not return any descendents or children.